# Not able to update 9007 numeric value for ag-grid numeric editor

Tags: ag-grid

In ag-grid I am able to update any value in numeric editable columns except 9007.
not only 9007, you can not update values ending with 9007.
this issue can be seen in there official documentation examples [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/?open=main.js&preview)

```
code https://plnkr.co/edit/?open=main.js&preview
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's added deliberately to the demo code on their documentation site (it's not part of the standard code)

```js
  // example - will reject the number if it contains the value 007
  // - not very practical, but demonstrates the method.
  isCancelAfterEnd() {
    var value = this.getValue();
    return value.indexOf('007') >= 0;
  }
```

- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-editors/

It's certainly a strange example they put in, so well spotted